# Can recursive compression be achieved?

Tags: compression

I want to ask that is **recursive compression or compressing again and again** possible or not. please give me reason for your answer

Comment: Sure, you can apply the same compression algorithm over and over again. Whether you can expect it to continue reducing the size of the data is another matter...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about information theory, not programming. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @NPE i know recursive compression is possible by running that code again but all current algorithms i saw on internet compressed 1 time and increased file size on the next compression function call

Comment: @newbee: That is to be expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know recursive compression is possible by running that code again and checking its length, but all current algorithms i saw on internet compressed for the 1st time only and increased file size on the next compression function call.

That is to be expected. If a certain lossless algorithm could squeeze more compression out of the data using the same method, it would probably have done this when run the first time round. Applying the same method again to the compressed data is very unlikely to yield further reduction in size.

What can be done, however, is combining several different compression algorithms. For example, [LZ77](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) combines well with [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a compression algorithm and you have an `input`. You compress by running the algorithm on the `input` you have received. Now, if you use the `output` of your algorithm as an `input` to a second call, then the `output` of the second call to your algorithm will be twice compressed. Let's consider this pseudo-code:

```
compress(input)
    //do stuff
    return output
compress end

recursiveCompression(input, depth)
    if depth > 0
        output <- compress(input)
        return recursiveCompression(output, depth - 1)
    else
        return input
    end if
recursiveCompression end
```

end you call `recursiveCompression` with your `input` and a positive integer `depth` value. The value of `depth` determines the number of compressions. Naturally, the compression might be inefficient above a certain `depth`. So the feasibility of several compressions depends on the `depth` and the algorithm.

Comment: i know recursive compression is possible by running that code again  and checking its length but all current algorithms i saw on internet compressed for the 1st time only and increased file size on the next compression function call

Comment: This is the answer to your question. If you want to compress something specifically, then ask another question, specifying what you want to compress and how you want it to be compressed. If you have a question about a specific algorithm, then ask another question about that algorithm. This question is too broad to get into compression details. As things are standing, your question of whether compression algorithms can be used recursively multiple times is answered above.